# How do I remove spaces between my buttons on my navbar?

Tags: css, navbar

I want to remove the spaces between my buttons on the navbar. any help?

i tried using `-->` and `<!--` between the `<li>` tags but it didn't remove spaces between my buttons on the nav bar.

I still have space between my buttons on the nav bar.

```css
  nav {
  height: 10vh;
  background: red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, red, red, black);
  .btn {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: white;
    padding: 23px 33px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
  }
  .btn:hover {
    background: black;
  }
  .nav-links {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    width: 50%;
    weight: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  .nav-links li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="nav-links">

  <li><button class="btn About"><a href="https://www.tsn.ca">About</a></button></li>
  <li><button class="btn Our Team"><a href="#">Our Team</a></button></li>
  <li><button class="btn Apps & Games"><a href="#">Apps & Games</a></button></li>
  <li><button class="btn Contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></button></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your css? You have to show us more than that, if you want us to help you.

Comment: Please, edit your question and add all this css. It's not easy to understand it here in the comments. And also, create a code snippet to show us what is the problem? I don't see any space between the buttons whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want, but you can simply remove `justify-content: space-around;` from your `.nav-links`. It will remove the space between them.

`justify-content: space-around;` is used to distribute evenly the elements inside the `div`'s width, creating this sensation of "extra" space.